# Twitter Single Sign On IOS using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, single-sign-on, twitter-fabric

I am implementing Twitter login in my app. I am able to login using Fabric and everything seems fine. Now i want the user to login only once and next time he/she opens the app a message should be displayed that "you are already signed in" or something like this and login button should not be there on the screen. I should also be able to get user's info (Twitter user name) when user launch the app second time, how can i achieve that ?
here is my code so far

```
import UIKit
import TwitterKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    var logInButton = TWTRLogInButton { (session, error) in
        if let unwrappedSession = session {

            print(session?.userName)
            print(session?.userID)


            //requesting Email address
            let client = TWTRAPIClient.clientWithCurrentUser()
            let request = client.URLRequestWithMethod("GET",
                URL: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json",
                parameters: ["include_email": "true", "skip_status": "true"],
                error: nil)

            client.sendTwitterRequest(request) { response, data, connectionError in
                print(data)
                print(response)

            }

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Logged In",
                message: "User \(unwrappedSession.userName) has logged in",
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert
            )
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("Login error:  \(error!.localizedDescription)");
        }

    }

    logInButton.loginMethods = [.SystemAccounts]

    // TODO: Change where the log in button is positioned in your view
    logInButton.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(logInButton)

    let store = Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore
    if let userID = store.session()?.userID {
        //store.logOutUserID(userID)
    }

}
}
```

Comment: why down votes ? you should specify resaon for down votes so that we can imporve our questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use following code it works for me

```
if((Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()?.userID) == nil)
 {
//show twitter login button
 }
else
 {
//user has already logged in take appropriate action
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: i was trying to accept but you know there is  a time limit

Comment: I didn't knew that.anyways thanx :)